# Importance of からだ in this sentence

Tags: syntax, nouns

I found this sentence in *Nihongo Sō-Matome*:

> A: また太っちゃった。。
>   B: あまいものばかり食べているからだよ。

Based on my understanding:

> A: (you're) fat again...
>   B: I only eat nothing but sweets.

I do not know why からだよ is there.

Should the translation be: *body eats nothing but sweets*? Is it ok to remove からだ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I think you got the actors the wrong way round.

> A また太っちゃった。
>   **I** ended up getting fat again.
>   B あまいものばかり食べているからだよ。
>   **That's because you** eat nothing but sweets.

Can you remove からだ? Grammatically you can, but it wouldn't sound natural in the same way that this English exchange would sound slightly awkward:

> A) I ended up getting fat again.
>   B) You eat nothing but sweets.

B's reply doesn't feel like part of the conversation does it? It just sounds like a random statement of fact.

Edit: I've just realised your problem. You thought からだ was 体 meaning body. But it isn't. It is から meaning 'because' plus the copula だ.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes I thought it was 'body' so I am confused.